# Extract stats from datetime intervals in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a MySQL database with some table stored as InnoDB type. One of them is `work_session` and its structure is:

```
`id` int(10) unsigned auto_increment primary
`project_id` int(10) unsigned index
`begin` datetime
`end` datetime
```

The table is used to register the time spent for each project. Of course in each row `end` is bigger than `begin`. Multiple rows may have the same `project_id` but intervals denoted by `begin` and `end` of rows with the same `project_id` don't overlap.

My aim is to extract some stats from this table. In particular:

- Time spent for each `project_id`
- Time spent in each day for each `project_id`, from the first recorded activity to now
- Time spent by hour of the day for each `project_id`
- Time spent by day of the week for each `project_id`

I was able to achieve this using PHP but I want to learn how to do it with MySQL.

I was able to obtain the first stat with

```
SELECT 
  `project_id`,
  SUM(`work_session_duration`) AS `project_duration`
FROM
  (SELECT 
    `project_id`,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `begin`, `end`) AS `work_session_duration`
   FROM `work_sessions`) AS `t1`
GROUP BY `project_id`
```

The other three stats are very similar, in particular the last two, but I'm not able to figure out a way to them with MySQL. Any hint, suggestion, link to some MySQL reference its appreciated.

Comment: Check out the [`EXTRACT()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) and use it in `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Statements like "Of course end is bigger than begin in each row, and no two begin-end ranges overlap for a given project" make me itchy. Unless there's business logic built into the database to ensure that, I wouldn't be comfortable trusting it to be so. I would only make the statement immediately after running a query to confirm it's true - and then, would probably include a caveat like "as of five minutes ago...". Admittedly not relevant to the question.

Comment: google mysql timstampdiff, you should find that it does more than seconds.  Time spent by day of week is another issue - you will need to convert your times to day of week formation (date_format()).   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: @RDFozz you're right but I wanted to keep the request and the example as simply as possible. Since ensuring that `end` is bigger than `start` and that intervals do not overlap for a given project is not my issue, I thought that it's better focusing on the extrapolation and save your time.

Comment: @RMathis I used seconds only because I don't need milliseconds. I know that for a large number of entries the error grows. However I don't understand your second statement: what I'm supposed to do after I convert my times with date_format?